# What does "rel" in `\mathrel` and `\stackrel` stands for?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Most latex tags have straightforward meanings, for instance,

`\sqrt` stands for/comes from "square root"

`\equiv` stands for/comes from "equivalent to"

What does "rel" in `\mathrel` and `\stackrel` stands for?

Comment: Probably "relation".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You asked,

> What does `rel` in `\mathrel` and `\stackrel` stand for?

The meaning of `rel` in `mathrel` quickly becomes fairly obvious if one considers the entire list of 13 types of math atoms; see also p. 158 of the TeXbook:

```
mathord, 'ord' for short -- something like 'x' and 'y'
mathop, 'op' for short -- large operators, e.g., '\sum' and '\prod'
bin   -- binary operation atoms, e.g., '+' and '-'
rel   -- relation operation atoms, e.g, '=', '<', and '>'
open  -- opening atom, e.g,, '(' and '['
close -- closing atom, e.g., ')' and ']'
punct -- punctuation atom, e.g., ','
inner -- (leading example: anything between '\left' and '\right')
over  -- overline atom, as in '\overline{x}'
under -- underline atome, as in '\underline{x}'
acc   -- accent atoms, as in '\hat{x}' and '\tilde{x}'
rad   -- radical atom, as in '\sqrt{x}'
vcent -- (argument of \vcenter directives)
```

One area where the status of the math atoms matters is in the spacing around binary and relational operators. E.g., if you examine the typeset output of `a+b` and `a=b`, you'll notice that the spacing around the `+` and `=` symbols is not the same; the space around the latter symbol is slightly greater (unless the symbols are encountered in scriptstyle or scriptscriptstyle mode). This difference in spacing embodies typographic rules developed over decades (centuries?) of fine math typesetting.

---

The `\mathrel` directive, which is a "TeX primitive" command, serves to change the math status of its argument to, you guessed it, `mathrel`. For example, writing `\mathrel+` changes the math status of `+` from `bin` (which is the default in most (all?) TeX systems) to `rel`. Aside: This is just an example; I am *not* suggesting that anyone would actually want to run this instruction. A more realistic example: Suppose that you want to denote the open interval from `-a` to `b` with `]-a,b[`. Writing the open interval directly in this way would, however, cause incorrect spacing between `]` (remember that its default math status is `close`) and the `-` symbol. To get the correct spacing between `]` and the unary `-` symbol, you could write

```
\mathopen] -a,b \mathclose[
```

thereby overriding the default math status of the `[` and `]` symbols. Better still, load the `mathtools` package and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to define a macro called, say, `\openint` with variable-sized delimiters as follows:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\openint}{]}{[}
```

This setup would allow you to write `\openint{-a,b}` in the body of the document.

---

Then there is `\stackrel` *macro*: It's a LaTeX command that allows placing superscript terms above some object (often, but not necessarily, an `=` symbol), making the math status of the combined object `mathrel`; e.g,, `\stackrel{!}{=}` places `!` above `=`, and the status of the combined object is `mathrel`. There is also a *package* called `stackrel`, which extends the functionality of `\stackrel` in two ways. First, it allows placing subscript terms below a main object, while setting the status of the combined object to `mathrel`. E.g.,

```
B \stackrel[x]{!}{=} C
```

places `x` below and `!` above the `=` symbol, and the math status of the combined object is set to `mathrel`. Second, it provides an additional macro called `\stackbin`, which allows placing subscript and superscript terms alongside a main object and setting the math status of the combined object to `mathbin`.

Comment: The explanation of `\stackrel` and `\stackbin` is incorrect. They actually make rel or bin atoms out of their arguments, which can be anything.

Comment: @egreg - Good catch! (I guess I was assuming implicitly that the "main" argument of `\stackrel` and `\stackbin` would naturally have default math status of `rel` and `bin`, resp. However, as you point out, that assumption is invalid.) Better now?

Comment: Note that `\mathrel` is not a “macro” but a TeX primitive command (see the definition of ⟨math atom⟩ on p. 291 of _The TeXbook_).  Note also that it is not necessary to sat `\mathrel{+}`, you can also say `\mathrel+`, and (contrary to what happens with macros) the two idioms have a subtly different meaning: in the latter case, the nucleus of the atom is the the symbol “+”, while in the former is a subsidary math list.  This subtle difference is usually inconsequential, but becomes significant in some cases.

Comment: @GuM - Thanks for this! I must confess to not being too exact, at times, with the difference between a "TeX primitive" command and a "macro". Hence, thanks for setting the record straight, so to say. I will correct the body of the answer, as neededThanks also for mentioning that both `\mathrel+` and `\mathrel{+}` are syntactically legal, with there being subtle (but at times significant) differences.

Comment: You are welcome!  Meanwhile, I have (upvoted and) found a meaningful example: compare `$\mathrel\sum$` with `$\mathrel{\sum}$` (`\showlists` inside math mode will be illuminating).  **Edit:**  In display math mode, the difference is even more striking: `\[ \mathrel\sum \neq \mathrel{\sum} \]`.

Comment: … I should have said `\[ {\mathrel\sum} \neq {\mathrel{\sum}} \]` (aesthetics matter too! ;-).

Comment: @GuM - In the example you give, it would seem that `{\mathrel{\sum}}` is to be preferred over `{\mathrel\sum}`, as the latter somehow manages to push the summation symbol below the baseline. Would you agree?

Comment: Actually, It depends on the circumstances, and more precisely on what you want to achieve.  Another example could be `$\mathop,$` vs, `$\mathop{,}$`: let’s say, for instance, that you want to define a “big operator” that looks like a comma, and let’s say that you want this “big operator” to be vertically centered along the math axis (as many “big operators” are); then `\mathop,` does what you want, but `\mathop{,}` does not.  (Perhaps a more realistic example could be `\mathop\circ` vs. `\mathop{\circ}`, but it’s harder to see the difference.)

Comment: @Mico You should replace `\mathopen{]}-a,b\mathclose{[}` by `\mathopen]-a,b\mathclose[` in your answer. Here the subtle difference that GuM mentions [in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505623/what-does-rel-in-mathrel-and-stackrel-stands-for#comment1277566_505626) actually matters: If you want to write ]a,b[² and you use `\mathopen{]}a,b\mathclose{[}^2` the vertical positioning of the superscript "²" is bad. See also tex.stackexchange.com/a/110220/227621.

Comment: @user227621 - Thanks. I guess it had not contemplated that somebody might want to take the square of an open interval. (Moreover, I must confess to not knowing what the square of an open interval is supposed to mean, unless (maybe?) it's used to denote the Cartesian product of the interval with itself...) Anyway, I'll be happy to update the answer so that nobody will possibly be misled.

Comment: @Mico Your guess is right, ]a,b[² can be used to denote the Cartesian product of ]a,b[ with itself.